# Gradle in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build

I can able to build the gradle jar in my local and the jar is seen in build/libs folder. But when I'm using Jenkins to build the same project using same jar command, why I cannot see /build/libs folder in Jenkins workspace?

Comment: I guess you’ll have to provide more information for anyone to be able to help you. Can you perhaps provide a [mcve] build script?

Comment: Thanks for you response. I've fixed this issue by adding the path in the root build script under gradle build. It worked.